# Pass next line as anew command

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I want to print the output of the stored procedure in a .csv file.
When I insert a single stored procedure such as 
`exec spGet Table 5 1,null,null,null,111,null,null,null,61,null,null,3;`
Along with its parameters it executes. But when I pass the same procedure multiple times with different parameters, It only executes the first Stored procedure and the remaining are ignored. In the CSV file i only get the first SP Output.

My code is as follows

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetSku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch swra = new Stopwatch();
        swra.Start();

        StreamWriter CsvfileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testfile.csv");
        string connectionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connectionString = "Data Source=My-PC-Name;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User            
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
         ID=Name;Password=********";

        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(textBox1.Text, cnn);
        cmd.CommandText = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 2000;
        using (cnn)
        {
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (CsvfileWriter)
            {
                //For getting the Table Headers
                DataTable Tablecolumns = new DataTable();

                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Tablecolumns.Columns.Add(rdr.GetName(i));
                }
                CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",",  
               Tablecolumns.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(csvfile =>   
               csvfile.ColumnName)));

                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    label1.Text = rdr["SKU"].ToString() + " " +    
                       rdr["SKUCode"].ToString();
                    CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(rdr["SKU"].ToString() + "," + 
               rdr["SKUCode"].ToString() + "," + 
                   rdr["Compliance_Curr"].ToString() + "," + 
                  rdr["Compliance_Prev"].ToString() + "," + 
             rdr["Difference"].ToString() + "," + 
            rdr["TotalSales_Curr"].ToString() + ",");
                }
                cnn.Close();

            }
        }
        swra.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(swra.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

}
```

I want to make sure that each procedure is executed differently and appended to the .csv file.

Comment: Where you are executing your SP multiple times in your code ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash I am using a text box in which I am placing my Execution of stored procedure along with its parameters

Comment: Are you appending data to your file or overwriting it each time?

Comment: @RePierre Yes I am appending data to a file that is stored in D drive,each time i run a query

Comment: @user3818862, does setting _cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;_ makes any difference for you ?

Comment: @RohitPrakash We are just executing a Stored Procedure that is already created

Comment: You need to look up sql injection. Your code is a textbook example of vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to overwriting the file each time. So what you have in there is actually the result of the last execution of the command.

The culprit is the following line:

```
StreamWriter CsvfileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testfile.csv");
```

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fysy0a4b(v=vs.100).aspx),

> If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

You need to use an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36b035cb(v=vs.100).aspx) of `StreamWriter` constructor which accepts a `bool` value specifying whether to append to the file or overwrite it.

```
var csvFileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testfile.csv", true);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer and the time you spent for solving my issue..adding true in StreamWriter helped me met my requirement.Thank you once again for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call stored procedure with names of parameters (which declared in stored procedure)?

For example: `EXECUTE spGet @Id = 1, @Number = 111, @....`

Comment: Thank you for your reply..But this will work properly for the first Execution but will not help when I run the second or the one after that.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating **StreamWriter object **everytime, you are clicking on **btnGetSku**, Try to make it member variable and then write. Data is not being appended,

```
StreamWriter CsvfileWriter = null;

private void btnGetSku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Stopwatch swra = new Stopwatch();
    swra.Start();

    if(CsvfileWriter == null)
       CsvfileWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\testfile.csv");
    string connectionString = null;
    SqlConnection cnn;
    connectionString = "Data Source=My-PC-Name;Initial Catalog=MyDB;User            
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     ID=Name;Password=********";

    cnn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(textBox1.Text, cnn);
    cmd.CommandText = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 2000;
    using (cnn)
    {
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        // Don't use using here. This disposes the streams
        //using (CsvfileWriter)
        {
            //For getting the Table Headers
            DataTable Tablecolumns = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Tablecolumns.Columns.Add(rdr.GetName(i));
            }
            CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",",  
           Tablecolumns.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(csvfile =>   
           csvfile.ColumnName)));

            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                label1.Text = rdr["SKU"].ToString() + " " +    
                   rdr["SKUCode"].ToString();
                CsvfileWriter.WriteLine(rdr["SKU"].ToString() + "," + 
           rdr["SKUCode"].ToString() + "," + 
               rdr["Compliance_Curr"].ToString() + "," + 
              rdr["Compliance_Prev"].ToString() + "," + 
         rdr["Difference"].ToString() + "," + 
        rdr["TotalSales_Curr"].ToString() + ",");
            }
            cnn.Close();

        }
    }
    swra.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(swra.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```